# How do I shorten my code in python turtle using new codes that haven't included (python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So my code is a bit long, I wan't to shorten it, anyone any new codes (to me) that haven't been concluded in my coding?

the topic is: "based square a drawn in an order (draw() function in my code, or rotated 90 degrees and draw), make the user type 2 input, which is length of the square, and times that it repeat, only odd lines are drawn in the draw() algorithm, and the even is rotated then drawn"

```
from turtle import *
import turtle as t
color("blue"); speed(0)
from math import sqrt
edge = int(input())
line = int(input())
linenum = 3
lineeve = 2
def draw(edge,line):
    t.begin_fill()
    t.rt(45)
    t.fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2)
    t.rt(90)
    t.fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2)
    t.rt(135)
    t.fd(edge)
    t.rt(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.fd(edge)
    t.rt(180)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.lt(45)
    t.fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)/2)
    t.rt(135)
    t.end_fill()
    t.fd(edge)
def base_square():
    global linenum
    draw(edge,line)
    t.pu(); t.fd(edge); t.lt(90); t.fd(edge); t.lt(90); t.pd()
    for i in range(1, (line+1)//2):  
        for _ in range(linenum):
            draw(edge,line)
            t.rt(135); t.fd(sqrt(edge**2*2)); t.rt(45)
        t.pu(); t.bk(edge*(linenum+1)); t.rt(90); t.fd(edge*2); t.lt(90); t.pd()
        linenum += 2
def evenline():
    global lineeve
    t.pu(); t.goto(0, 0); t.bk(edge/2); t.rt(90); t.fd(edge); t.lt(90); t.fd(lineeve * edge); t.rt(90); t.pd()
    for b in range(line//2):
        for l in range(lineeve):
            draw(edge, line); t.lt(180)
        lineeve += 2
        t.pu(); t.rt(90); t.fd(edge); t.lt(90); t.fd(edge*2); t.lt(90); t.fd(lineeve * edge); t.rt(90); t.pd()    
def runcode():
    base_square()
    evenline()
runcode()
```

Comment: Mentioned in a previous post, but shortening code is not the goal, per se, unless you're playing code golf (which isn't on topic here). Cramming commands on one line with `;` makes the code hard to understand for yourself and everyone else. Best to use a code formatter like [Black](https://github.com/psf/black). It'll make your code instantly more readable. Avoid legacy Logo abbreviations like `fd`.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal to "shorten" your code is best achieved by making your code more readable with an efficient algorithm.  For example, consider `draw()`.  We can visualize it as two symmetric halves that can be drawn in a loop:

[image]

```
def draw(edge):
    diagonal = sqrt(2 * edge**2)

    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(edge)
        t.right(135)

        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(diagonal/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(diagonal/2)
        t.end_fill()

        t.right(135)
```

Note that the `line` argument to your `draw()` routine isn't used.  Also, unless there's somewhere else obviously better, have your routine leave the turtle where it was when the routine started, making programming with your routine easier.

The variables `linenum` and `lineeve`, don't need to be global, they can be local to the two routines that use them.  Here's my complete code rework:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import sqrt

def draw(t, edge):
    diagonal = sqrt(2 * edge**2)

    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(edge)
        t.right(135)

        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(diagonal/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(diagonal/2)
        t.end_fill()

        t.right(135)

def base_square(t):
    linenum = 1

    for _ in range(line//2 + 1):
        for _ in range(linenum):
            draw(t, edge)
            t.forward(edge)

        linenum += 1

        t.penup()
        t.backward(edge * linenum)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(edge*2)
        t.left(90)

        linenum += 1

def evenline(t):
    lineeve = 2

    t.forward(edge/2)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(edge)

    for _ in range(line//2):
        for _ in range(lineeve):
            draw(t, edge)
            t.penup()
            t.setx(t.xcor() + edge)

        lineeve += 1

        t.forward(edge*2)
        t.setx(t.xcor() - lineeve * edge)

        lineeve += 1

def runcode():
    base_square(turtle)
    turtle.home()
    evenline(turtle)

edge = int(input("Block size: "))
line = int(input("Pyramid height: "))

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color('blue')
turtle.speed('fastest')

runcode()

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

If you find yourself importing turtle twice, two different ways, there's something wrong.  The above may seem more verbose, but it is actually about the same number of characters as your original code.  But hopefully, easier to read and easier to debug.